# Bind data to view from rest proxy in store in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, json, rest, extjs

I'm trying to populate data from JSON that I get via a rest URL into my view. For some reason the JSON value does not display.

Here is my view:

```
Ext.define('Project.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: 'border',
    bodyBorder: false,
    defaults: {
        collapsible: false,
        split: false
    },
    viewModel: {
        type: 'animalClassViewModel'  
    },
    items: [
        {
            region:'north',
            autoHeight: true,
            margin: '0 0 0 0',         
            bind: {
                html: '<p style="text-align: center;">{animalClass.name}</p>' // this should display "mammals" from json
            }
        },
        {
            region: 'center',
            margin: '0 0 0 0',
            items:[
                {
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'tabPanel'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },

    ]
});
```

Here is my view model:

```
Ext.define('Project.view.main.AnimalClassViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

    alias: 'viewmodel.animalClassViewModel',

    stores: {
        animalClass: {
            model: 'Project.model.AnimalClassModel',
            autoLoad:true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                url: 'api/animalClass',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'name' // this is probably unnecessary 
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My model:

```
Ext.define('Project.model.AnimalClassModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: ['name']
});
```

And this is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/animalClass"
    }
  },
  "name" : "mammals"
}
```

I tried just `{animalClass}` in the view, but it returned the entire object, which makes sense. But I'm not sure why `{animalClass.name}` doesn't display "mammals".

I tried following this example: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-associations but it didn't work for me. It doesn't seem like it includes all of the components that are in play for it to work.

Comment: `class` is a `reserved keyword`. Don't use it, it can cause the problems you are facing. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: I actually didn't use "class" in my real code. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: `animalClass` is a store, a collection of records. So saying `animalClass.name` doesn't make sense. Instead, you want to define the proxy on the model and use the `links` config to load a single instance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Evan. This example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6uj helped me to arrive at my solution: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tfc

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the [rootProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-rootProperty) to point to a array of data (in your json). This means that everything inside that property will be bind as data to the [store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store):

Proxy on the store:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url : 'users.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'animals'
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/animalClass"
    }
  },
  "animals": {
    "name" : "mammals"
  }
}
```